# Use R to reduce a dataset to only rows that have matching data in two separate columns

Tags: r, bigdata

I am trying to reduce a massive data set to only the rows that match in the "FIRSTNAME" column and also the "SSN" column. In order to help clarify I made a small set.

Very small sample

```
CUSTNUM FIRSTNAME SSN
 1234     Matt    111
 4321     Mark    222
 5678     Mike    333
 9875     Matt    444
 1092     Matt    111
```

I want it to return

```
CUSTNUM FIRSTNAME SSN
 1234     Matt    111
 1092     Matt    111
```

Because they match in both columns.

My dataset has over 2 million rows of customer data in it so I need a way to id possible duplicate records.

Comment: Try with `duplicated` i.e. `df[duplicated(df[2:3])|duplicated(df[2:3], fromLast = TRUE),]`

Answer (score 2):

There's a handy function for this in base r:

```
# suppose you have a dataframe, df, and you want to know which rows 
# have duplicate values in both the FIRSTNAME and SSN columns together:
df$dup <- duplicated(df[,c('name','SSN')],fromLast=FALSE)
df$dup <- ifelse(duplicated(df[,c('name','SSN')],fromLast=TRUE),yes=TRUE,no=df$dup)

# return dups
df.answer <- df[which(df$dup),]
```

Comment: I think your `ifelse` can be simplified to just `duplicated(df[,c('name','SSN')],fromLast=TRUE) | df$dup`. And if you want to speed things up a little, just keep `dup` as a vector instead of adding it to the data frame.

Answer (score 2):

```
# Sample data
df <- read.table(text = 
   "CUSTNUM FIRSTNAME SSN
    1234     Matt    111
    4321     Mark    222
    5678     Mike    333
    9875     Matt    444
    1092     Matt    111", sep = "", header = T);
```

`subset`ting based on the `paste`d columns:

```
subset(df, duplicated(paste(FIRSTNAME, SSN)) | duplicated(paste(FIRSTNAME, SSN), fromLast = T))
#1    1234      Matt 111
#5    1092      Matt 111
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, with `dplyr`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(FIRSTNAME, SSN) %>% 
  filter(n() > 1)

# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   FIRSTNAME, SSN [1]
  CUSTNUM FIRSTNAME   SSN
    <int>    <fctr> <int>
1    1234      Matt   111
2    1092      Matt   111
```